# Django project can't be deployed to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy Django project.
Firstly, I get this error:

```
Counting objects: 74, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Writing objects: 100% (74/74), 25.74 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 74 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching https://codon-
buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz buildpack
remote:        More info: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to nicoplus.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/nicoplus.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nicoplus.git'
```

Then, I set the buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

But, it still throw an error:

```
remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz buildpack
```

So, any solution to this problem?

PS: python is 2.7.12

Comment: Do you have a requirements.txt file? (And added to your git repository?) I bet that's what the Python buildpack keys off of....

Comment: Thx for the comment above, I add a wrong 'requirement.txt' to my repository.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) I came across this:

*"A number of additional, unsupported runtimes are available. However, we only endorse and support the use of Python 3.6.1 and 2.7.13."*

My guess is that using 2.7.12 is throwing it off.

Comment: Thx for your help, but python 2.7.12 still works. I made a stupid mistake that 'requirements.txt' was written as 'requirement.txt'. LOL~